# Running test file on directory of similair files and recording results

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, unix, scripting

I have a directory of python files that look like this

```
documents/needTesting/
                      algorithmV1.py
                      algorithmV2.py
                      ....
                      algorithmVn.py
```

They all take the same parameters and have similar outputs.
Is there a way for me to test all of them at once and store the results in a file?

Ideally, I would like to have the result look like this.

```
V1 offset: 0.2% Runtime: 50ms
V2 offset: 1.4% Runtime: 34ms
...
Vn offset: ...  Runtime: ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
for f in documents/needTesting/*.py; do
    python3 "$f" >> results.txt
done
```

You can add command line inputs just before or after `"$f"`. Make sure that all your python files print 1 line (Ideally - V1 offset: 0.2% Runtime: 50ms). To get the runtime you can use the time module (inside each python file).

If you don't want to change each python file, you can wrap them by making a file `wrapper.py`, which takes one command-line argument, imports that file and times it/gets the result. Look up dynamically importing/using modules.

the shell script for that command would be something like:

```sh
for f in documents/needTesting/*.py; do
    python3 wrapper.py "$f" >> results.txt
done
```